# Startup command is not saved in Linux Mint 15

Tags: linux-mint

I'm having problems adding a program to run at startup in Linux Mint 15.

I want to add WhatPulse:

```
sh -c "sleep 15 && /home/nicu/Documents/whatpulse"
```

but after reboot it is automatically changed to this

```
/home/nicu/Documents/whatpulse -delaystartup
```

Basically it doesn't save the command.

Not sure if this is related to other problem that I have: launching apps from Synaptic doesn't work, but they work fine if I run them from terminal (i.e. Software Manager works only if I run it from termina: sudo mintinstall)

Thank you,
Nicu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the command line way of doing, but works all the same.

- Open your home folder
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Open .config
- Open autostart
- Drag and drop the program you want to run at startup

BTW, I'm running MATE.  Not sure if that's going to make a difference with whatever you're running.

Comment: I know this is an old question and answer, but what if you need to autostart a program that needs to be run from specific folder say `/home/accounting/myprogram.` You simply can't drag and drop a copy of your program into autostart folder. Am I right? My question is this. How do you account for the work path for your program within autostart folder?